# Angular title error: angular doesn't show me full title

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

I am working on html through angularjs.

While I am working on the title of the page, it shows me the part of title

What I mean about it is that the image below shows you.

[image]

My code for html is below,

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="page-header section-dark" style="background-image: url('./assets/img/Cover1.jpg')">
    <div class="content-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="title-brand">
          <div class="angular-logo"><img alt="" src="./assets/img/asia-logo.png"></div>
            <h1 class="presentation-title"> ASIA-SMS</h1>
          

          <div class="type">pro</div>
          <div class="fog-low">
            <img src="./assets/img/sections/fog-low.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="fog-low right">
            <img src="./assets/img/sections/fog-low.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The CSS classes would make this issue.

Comment: You have tagged both `angularjs` and `angular`. Please edit and remove one of the tags as `angularjs` and `angular` are not the same. Please also share your `css` file